# T1 space, there all closed G-delta set is zero-set, but isn't normal

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

In Engelking's General topology, in exercises part, there is Ju. M. Smirnov's charactarization of normal spaces:

T1 space is normal iff following properties hold (both):
a. every closed G-delta set is zero-set;
b. for every F closed set and G open set, such that F is in G, there exist M closed G-delta set, such that F is in M and M is in G.

This equivalency is not hard to prove. Than there is written that, neither of the properties by itself implies the normaliry of X. For b, maybe for example may use co-finite topology on countable set, because any closed set is also G-delta (Also, for that example may also used Niemetzki plane by the same argument).

But, I can't find example of T1 space, which has property a. and is not normal. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have a hunch that Mrówka $\Psi$-space is such an example.

Comment: For trivial example we can also use Particular point topogy, i.e. the topology when where exist x from X such that U is open iff x is in U or U is empty set. In this case the only closed G-delta sets is X and empty set, which are zero sets. but this topology is not normal.

Comment: I agree, and the $\Psi$-space proof (it's an obvious idea to try) will work too, I think. Maybe Engelking was thinking of $(\omega_1 +1)^2  \setminus \{(\omega_1, \omega_1)\}$, another candidate to try..

Comment: But the particular point topology is not $T_1$ though.